# Create a confusion matrix from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, confusion-matrix

I have this data frame called `conf_mat` with two columns including predicted values and reference values in each objects. I have 20 objects in this dataframe.

```
 dput(Conf_mat)
structure(list(Predicted = c(100, 200, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 
200, 100, 200, 500, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 500, 200
), Reference = c(600, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 500, 
500, 500, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200)), .Names = c("Predicted", 
"Reference"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a confusion matrix out of this table with this kind of structure which will be filled in by the `Conf_mat` dataframe. This will be allow me to compute an accuracu assessment of my classification. Thanks for your help.

```
    100 200 300 400 500 600
100  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
200  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
300  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
400  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
500  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
600  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Try the following:

```
table(Conf_mat)
```

**2)** If you want to force levels 100, 200, ..., 600 to appear:

```
conf_mat_tab <- table(lapply(Conf_mat, factor, levels = seq(100, 600, 100)))
```

**3)** You could also try this:

```
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(conf_mat_tab) # conf_mat_tab from (2)
```

which gives:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

         Reference
Predicted 100 200 300 400 500 600
      100   0   9   0   0   1   1
      200   0   6   0   0   1   0
      300   0   0   0   0   0   0
      400   0   0   0   0   0   0
      500   0   1   0   0   1   0
      600   0   0   0   0   0   0

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.35            
                 95% CI : (0.1539, 0.5922)
    No Information Rate : 0.8             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

                  Kappa : 0.078           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: 100 Class: 200 Class: 300 Class: 400 Class: 500 Class: 600
Sensitivity                  NA     0.3750         NA         NA     0.3333       0.00
Specificity                0.45     0.7500          1          1     0.9412       1.00
Pos Pred Value               NA     0.8571         NA         NA     0.5000        NaN
Neg Pred Value               NA     0.2308         NA         NA     0.8889       0.95
Prevalence                 0.00     0.8000          0          0     0.1500       0.05
Detection Rate             0.00     0.3000          0          0     0.0500       0.00
Detection Prevalence       0.55     0.3500          0          0     0.1000       0.00
Balanced Accuracy            NA     0.5625         NA         NA     0.6373       0.50
```