# How to make a confusion matrix from comparing prediction results of two algorithms?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I applied two unsupervised algorithms to the same data, and would like to make a confusion matrix out of results, how should I achieve it in **R**?

An example with R codes like following:

```
xx.1 <- c(41, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 11, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4)
xx.2 <- matrix(xx.1, nrow = 5)
rownames(xx.2) <- paste("Algo1", 1:5, sep = "_")
colnames(xx.2) <- paste("Algo2", 1:5, sep = "_")
xx.2
```

xx.2 is the predicting results of two algorithms, the numbers show how many observation are classified as Algo1_X and Algo2_X:

```
       Algo2_1 Algo2_2 Algo2_3 Algo2_4 Algo2_5
Algo1_1      41       0       0       0       0
Algo1_2       0       0      11       0       1
Algo1_3       4       0       8       0       1
Algo1_4       0       0       0       3       0
Algo1_5       0       7       0       0       4
```

The problem is, how should I rearrange the matrix to get a confusion matrix, by using the results of Algo1 as reference? There are two questions:

1. Determine the corresponding between two algorithms, i.e., the method I think is that the most similar classification should be paired;
2. The matrix is rearranged so that dialog line have the largest intersect value.

Here, Algo2_1 and Algo1_1 have the largest intersect value and their are a pair; then Algo1_2 and Algo2_3 should be a pair since they have the second largest value in the left column/rows, so Algo2_3 should be moved to the second column.

How could I do it easily in R? or there are packages available for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the example matrix that you're showing for demonstrating how you want your output to be?

Comment: no, I want to make a confusion matrix from the example matrix, by rearrange the order of columns.

Comment: You might have a look at caret package. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631814/create-a-confusion-matrix-from-a-dataframe